# How to center-align a full-height image when it is wider than the screen?

Tags: html, css

I need to center-align my main div image which I have working on wider screens. But when I reduce the width of the screen, the image always starts from the left and is cropped off at the right.

I need the image to be centered within screen size, even if it is too wide.

[image]

```css
    body {
    background-color: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
    .vid {
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="vid" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/testbg.jpg">
```

Comment: have you tried `align: center;` yet?

Comment: @tacoshy 1. `align: center` isn't a valid CSS property and 2. simple alignment won't make a block element move out of the container on the left side.

Comment: @FluffyKitten the question when I asked it, was just about one item without container to be centered

Comment: @tacoshy 1. `align:center` still isn't valid CSS. and 2. the question hasn't changed so alignment would not have fixed anything when you posted

Answer (score 0):

You may try to apply these styles to the img's parent:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thx guys, but please see the example image i attached. vertical height is 100% always. if the screen window is small the image should still center but stay the same vertical size.

Comment: I can do it normally with: (width: 800px; margin-left: -400px; /* half width */) but my wide is auto (unknown) so i don't know the width in px value to use as the height is 100vh!

Comment: have just edit the code, please see if that works or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the height, you should specify the width. Here is an example:

```
  .vid {
    width:90%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin:0;
    
}
    .vid {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top:10vw;
    
}
```

```html
<img class="vid" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/testbg.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) lets you specify how the image should fit into the space:

```
.vid {
    object-fit: cover; /* fill the whole container centring image if it doesn't fit */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;       /* object-fit needs to have a width set */
}
```

Using `object-fit:cover` will make the image fill (or "cover") the whole space, cropping off the left and right if it is too wide for the space so that it is centred.

**Working Example - full cover**

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.vid {
  object-fit:cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="vid" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/testbg.jpg">
```

**Working Example Setting a max height & width** - you can also set a min/max height or width on the image too if you need to - these can be set to any specific value (e.g. `800px`) or % (e.g. `max-width:100%`):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.vid {
  object-fit:cover;
  /*  e.g. to limit the size of the image to its actual size */
  max-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 500px; /* for example, but not required */
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<img class="vid" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/testbg.jpg">
```

Comment: fluffy, your solution is close but does not show the full width of the image which is 800px? could you set this in your example...

Comment: @stewy Sure, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean - do you mean that once the screen is at least 800px you don't want it to fill the screen? In the 2nd example I've set the `max-width` to `1000px`, if you change that to `800px` is that what you want to do? If you, just let me know what you are looking for!

Comment: it's ok fluffy i got the solution:    object-fit:cover;
   height: 100vh;
   max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use background image when you want to fill a div with a image(most of the time).I hope this this will help you resolve your issue.

```css
    body {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
    .vid {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('http://wizzfree.com/pix/testbg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid" > </div>
```